# Can we tweak "a -> a" function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell `id` function is defined on type level as `id :: a -> a` and implemented as just returning its argument without any modification, but if we have some type introspection with `TypeApplications` we can try to modify values without breaking type signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

module Main where

class TypeOf a where
  typeOf :: String

instance TypeOf Bool where
  typeOf = "Bool"

instance TypeOf Char where
  typeOf = "Char"  

instance TypeOf Int where
  typeOf = "Int"  
   
tweakId :: forall a. TypeOf a => a -> a
tweakId x 
  | typeOf @a == "Bool" = not x
  | typeOf @a == "Int" = x+1
  | typeOf @a == "Char" = x
  | otherwise = x
```

This fail with error:

> "Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Bool’"

But I don't see any problems here (type signature satisfied):

My question is:

1. How can we do such a thing in a Haskell?
2. If we can't, that is theoretical\philosophical etc reasons for this?
3. If this implementation of tweak_id is not "original id", what are theoretical roots that `id` function must not to do any modifications on term level. Or can we have many implementations of `id :: a -> a` function (I see that in practice we can, I can implement such a function in Python for example, but what the theory behind Haskell says to this?)

Comment: nit: if you change the input your function isn't really `id` any more, why not name it just `tweak`?

Comment: If we look on this in terms of category theory, such a function will be Id function? it's id: a -> a , why not?

Comment: Well `id` is the function which returns it's argument *unaltered* while your function is just a function that returns the same type it receives as argument. Calling it `<something>Id` is guaranteed to lead to some confusion somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I change id to "a -> a" function

Comment: `forall a. TypeOf a => a -> a` is not `a -> a`. These are completely different types. "without breaking type signature" isn't.

Answer (score 10):

You need GADTs for that.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Type.Equality

tweakId :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> a
tweakId x
  | Just Refl <- eqT @a @Int = x + 1
  -- etc. etc.
  | otherwise                = x
```

Here we use `eqT @type1 @type2` to check whether the two types are equal. If they are, the result is `Just Refl` and pattern matching on that `Refl` is enough to convince the type checker that the two types are indeed equal, so we can use `x + 1` since `x` is now no longer only of type `a` but *also* of type `Int`.

This check requires runtime type information, which we usually do not have due to Haskell's type erasure property. The information is provided by the `Typeable` type class.

This can also be achieved using a user-defined class like your `TypeOf` if we make it provide a custom GADT value. This can work well if we want to encode some constraint like "type `a` is either an `Int`, a `Bool`, or a `String`" where we statically know what types to allow (we can even recursively define a set of allowed types in this way). However, to allow *any* type, including ones that have not yet been defined, we need something like `Typeable`. That is also very convenient since any user-defined type is automatically made an instance of `Typeable`.

Answer (score 8):

> This fail with error: "Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Bool’"
> But I don't see any problems here

Well, what if I add this instance:

```
instance TypeOf Float where
  typeOf = "Bool"
```

Do you see the problem now? Nothing prevents somebody from adding such an instance, no matter how silly it is. And so the compiler can't possibly make the assumption that having checked `typeOf @a == "Bool"` is sufficient to actually use `x` as being of type `Bool`.

You *can* squelch the error if you are confident that nobody will add malicious instances, by using unsafe coercions.

```
import Unsafe.Coerce

tweakId :: forall a. TypeOf a => a -> a
tweakId x 
  | typeOf @a == "Bool" = unsafeCoerce (not $ unsafeCoerce x)
  | typeOf @a == "Int" = unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce x+1 :: Int)
  | typeOf @a == "Char" = unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce x :: Char)
  | otherwise = x
```

but I would not recommend this. The correct way is to not use strings as a poor man's type representation, but instead the standard [`Typeable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:Typeable) which is actually tamper-proof and comes with suitable GADTs so you don't need manual unsafe coercions. See [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75372889/745903).

As an alternative, you could also use *type-level strings* and a functional dependency to make the unsafe coercions safe:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FunctionalDependencies
           , ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax, TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (KnownSymbol, symbolVal)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Unsafe.Coerce

class KnownSymbol t => TypeOf a t | a->t, t->a

instance TypeOf Bool "Bool"
instance TypeOf Int "Int"

tweakId :: ∀ a t . TypeOf a t => a -> a
tweakId x = case symbolVal @t Proxy of
  "Bool" -> unsafeCoerce (not $ unsafeCoerce x)
  "Int" -> unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce x + 1 :: Int)
  _ -> x
```

The trick is that the fundep `t->a` makes writing another instance like

```
instance TypeOf Float "Bool"
```

a compile error right there.

Of course, really the most sensible approach is probably to not bother with any kind of manual type equality at all, but simply use the class right away for the behaviour changes you need:

```
class Tweakable a where
  tweak :: a -> a

instance Tweakable Bool where
  tweak = not
instance Tweakable Int where
  tweak = (+1)
instance Tweakable Char where
  tweak = id
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are both very good for covering the ways you *can* do something like this in Haskell. But I thought it was worth adding something speaking more to this part of the question:

> 2. If we can't, that is theoretical\philosophical etc reasons for this?

Actually Haskellers *do* generally rely quite strongly on the theory that forbids something like your `tweakId` from existing with type `forall a. a -> a`. (Even though there are ways to cheat, using things like `unsafeCoerce`; this is usually considered bad style if you haven't done something like in leftaroundabout's answer, where a class with functional dependencies ensures the unsafe coerce is always valid)

Haskell uses **parametric polymorphism**<sup>1</sup>. That means we can write code that works on multiple types because it will treat them all the same; the code only uses operations that will work *regardless* of the specific type it is invoked on. This is expressed in Haskell types by using type variables; a function with a variable in its type can be used with any type at all substituted for the variable, because every single operation in the function definition will work regardless of what type is chosen.

About the simplest example is indeed the function `id`, which might be defined like this:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

Because it's parametrically polymorphic, we can simply choose any type at all we like and use `id` as if it was defined on that type. For example as if it were any of the following:

```
id :: Bool -> Bool
id x = x

id :: Int -> Int
id x = x

id :: Maybe (Int -> [IO Bool]) -> Maybe (Int -> [IO Bool])
id x = x
```

But to ensure that the definition *does* work for **any** type, the compiler has to check a very strong restriction. Our `id` function can **only** use operations that don't depend on any property of any specific type at all. We can't call `not x` because the `x` might not be a `Bool`, we can't call `x + 1` because the `x` might not be a number, can't check whether `x` is equal to anything because it might not be a type that supports equality, etc, etc. In fact there is almost nothing you *can* do with `x` in the body of `id`. We can't even *ignore* `x` and return some other value of type `a`; this would require us to write an expression for a value that can be of *any* type at all and the only things that can do that are things like `undefined` that don't evaluate to a value at all (because they throw exceptions). It's often said that in fact there is only *one* valid function with type `forall a. a -> a` (and that is `id`)<sup>2</sup>.

This restriction on what you can do with values whose type contains variables isn't just a restriction for the sake of being picky, it's actually a huge part of what makes Haskell types *useful*. It means that just looking at the type of a function can often tell you quite a bit about what it can possibly do, and once you get used to it Haskellers rely on this kind of thinking all the time. For example, consider this function signature:

```
map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Just from this type (and the assumption that the code doesn't do anything dumb like add in extra `undefined` elements of the list) I can tell:

1. All of the items in the resulting list come are results of the function input; `map` will have no other way of producing values of type `b` to put in the list (except `undefined`, etc).
2. All of the items in the resulting list correspond to something in the input list mapped through the function; `map` will have no way of getting any `a` values to feed to the function (except `undefined`, etc)
3. If any items of the input list are dropped or re-ordered, it will be done in a "blind" way that isn't considering the elements at all, only their position in the list; `map` ultimately has no way of testing any property of the `a` and `b` values to decide which order they should go in. For example it might leave out the third element, or swap the 2nd and 76th elements if there are at least 100 elements, etc. But if it applies rules like that it will have to *always* apply them, regardless of the actual items in the list. It cannot e.g. drop the 4th element if it is less than the 5th element, or only keep outputs from the function that are "truthy", etc.

None of this would be true if Haskell allowed parametrically polymorphic types to have Python-like definitions that check the type of their arguments and then run *different* code. Such a definition for `map` could check if the function is supposed to return integers and if so return `[1, 2, 3, 4]` regardless of the input list, etc. So the type checker would be enforcing a lot less (and thus catching fewer mistakes) if it worked this way.

This kind of reasoning is formalised in the concept of **free theorems**; it's literally possible to derive formal proofs about a piece of code from its type (and thus get theorems for free). You can google this if you're interested in further reading, but Haskellers generally use this concept informally rather doing real proofs.

Sometimes we do need non-parametric polymorphism. The main tool Haskell provides for that is type classes. If a type variable has a class constraint, then there will be an interface of class methods provided by that constraint. For example the `Eq a` constraint allows `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool` to be used, and your own `TypeOf a` constraint allows `typeOf @a` to be used. Type class methods **do** allow you to run different code for different types, so this breaks parametricity. Even just adding `Eq a` to the type of `map` means I can no longer assume property 3 from above.

```
map :: forall a b. Eq a => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Now `map` can tell whether some of the items in the original list are equal to each other, so it can use that to decide whether to include them in the result, and in what order. Likewise `Monoid a` or `Monoid b` would allow `map` to break the first two properties by using `mempty :: a` to produce new values that weren't in the list originally or didn't come from the function. If I add `Typeable` constraints I can't assume anything, because the function could do all of the Python-style checking of types to apply special-case logic, make use of existing values it knows about if `a` or `b` happen to be those types, etc.

So something like your `tweakId` cannot be given the type `forall a. a -> a`, for theoretical reasons that are also extremely practically important. But if you need a function that *behaves* like your `tweakId` adding a class constraint was the right thing to do to break out of the constraints of parametricity. However simply being able to get a `String` for each type isn't enough; `typeOf @a == "Int"` doesn't tell the type checker that `a` can be used in operations requiring an `Int`. It knows that in that branch the equality check returned `True`, but that's just a `Bool`; the type checker isn't able to reason backwards to **why** this particular `Bool` is `True` and deduce that it could only have happened if `a` were the type `Int`. But there are alternative constructs using GADTs that *do* give the type checker additional knowledge within certain code branches, allowing you to check types at runtime and use different code for each type. The class `Typeable` is specifically designed for this, but it's a hammer that completely bypasses parametricity; I think most Haskellers would prefer to keep more type-based reasoning intact where possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> Parametric polymorphism is in contrast to class-based polymorphism you may have seen in OO languages (where each class says how a method is implemented for objects of that specific class), or ad-hoc polymophism (as seen in C++) where you simply define multiple definitions with the same name but different types and the types at each application determine which definition is used. I'm not covering those in detail, but the key distinction is both of them allow the definition to have *different* code for each supported type, rather than guaranteeing the *same* code will process all supported types.

<sup>2</sup> It's not 100% true that there's only one valid function with type `forall a. a -> a` unless you hide some caveats in "valid". But if you don't use any unsafe features (like `unsafeCoerce` or the foreign language interface), then a function with type `forall a. a -> a` will either always throw an exception or it will return its argument unchanged.

The "always throws an exception" isn't terribly useful so we usually assume an unknown function with that type isn't going to do that, and thus ignore this possibility.

There are multiple ways to implement "returns its argument unchanged", like `id x = head . head . head $ [[[x]]]`, but they can only differ from the normal `id` in being slower by building up some structure around `x` and then immediately tearing it down again. A caller that's only worrying about correctness (rather than performance) can treat them all the same.

Thus, ignoring the "always undefined" possibility and treating all of the dumb elaborations of `id x = x` the same, we come to the perspective where we can say "there's only one function with `forall a. a -> a`".